# Bigtable data modeling and query with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

This is my first time using BigTable I can't tell if I don't understand bigtable modeling or how to use the python library.

Some background on what I'm storing:

I am storing time series events that let's say have two columns name and message, my rowkey is "#200501163223" so rowkey includes time in this format '%y%m%d%H%M%S'

Let's say later I needed to add another column called "type".

Also, it possible that there can be two events at the same second.

So this is what I end up with if I store 2 events, with the second event having the additional "type" data:

```
account#200501163223
  Outbox:name                               @ 2020/05/01-17:32:16.412000
    "name1"
  Outbox:name                               @ 2020/05/01-16:41:49.093000
    "name2"
  Outbox:message                            @ 2020/05/01-17:32:16.412000
    "msg1"
  Outbox:message                            @ 2020/05/01-16:41:49.093000
    "msg2"
  Outbox:type                               @ 2020/05/01-16:35:09.839000
    "temp"
```

When I query this rowkey using python bigtable library, I get back a dictionary with my column names as keys and data as a list of Cell objects

"name" and "message" key would have 2 objects, and "type" would only have one object since it was only part of the second event.

My question is, how do I know which event, 1 or 2 that "type" value of temp belongs to? Is this model just wrong and I have to ensure only one event can be stored under a rowkey which would be hard to do.. or is there a trick I'm missing in the library to be able to associate the events data accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question tasha, and something I've come across before too, so thanks for asking it.

In Bigtable, there isn't a concept of having the columns be connected from the same write. This can be very helpful to some people by having a lot of flexibility with what you can do with various columns and versions, but in your case it causes this issue.

The best way to handle this is with 2 steps.

1. Make sure [each time you write to a row](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writing-data) you use the same timestamp for that write. That would look like this:

   ```
       timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

       row_key = "account#200501163223"

       row = table.direct_row(row_key)
       row.set_cell(column_family_id,
                    "name",
                    "name1",
                    timestamp)
       row.set_cell(column_family_id,
                    "type",
                    "temp",
                    timestamp)

       row.commit()
   ```
2. Then when you are querying your database, you can apply a filter to only get either the latest version or latest N versions, or a scan based on timestamp ranges.

   `rows = table.read_rows(filter_=row_filters.CellsColumnLimitFilter(2))`

Here are a [few snippets with examples on how to use a filter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigtable/snippets/filters/filter_snippets.py) with Bigtable reads. They should be added to the documentation soon.

Comment: thank you! I'm going to test out this approach to see if it solves my issue.

Comment: I think I should be able to achieve what I need by grouping data by timestamp (your example helped to ensure same cells share the same timestamp). The link to filters options was also very helpful!

Comment: Happy to help, if you're able to mark this as the accepted answer too that would rock. Thanks!